# How to get the objects that are not selected via mouseclicklistener from an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a JLabel[] which holds jlabels. I have stored 5 elements in that array and assigned a mouseClickListener too all of those labels using a for loop like thus:

```
JLabel rollHumanLabels[] = new JLabel[5];

 for (int humanLabelCounter = 0; humanLabelCounter < rollHumanLabels.length; humanLabelCounter++) {
        rollHumanLabels[humanLabelCounter] = new JLabel();
        rollHumanLabels[humanLabelCounter].addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
                }
```

And I have a class for the mouse listener:

```
public class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

  }
}
```

Now what I essentially want to do is to get the JLabels that are not selected.I've tried different ways but they don't really work. E.g. I wrote a bunch of if statements inside the mouseClicked method like:

```
if(e.getSource() == rollHumanLabels[0]){//Add it to an an integar of 1 to the arrayList}
if(e.getSource() == rollHumanLabels[1]){//Add it to an integar value of 2 to the rrayList}
```

And then tried looping through the arraylist that I added the values to but I didn't know how to get the ones that were not selected since my logic was not right. Could someone tell me how to go on about to do this procedure

Comment: I see an array not an ArrayList for rollHumanLabels. If it were an ArrayList you could do rollHumanLabels.remove(e.getSource()) which would remove any element from the list that was clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

It's a few way to do this. One of them is created a own `JLabel` implementation where you can save information, that `JLabel` was clicked. It's could look like this.

```
public class MyJLabel extends JLabel {
    private boolean selected;

    public MyJLabel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                selected = true;
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

And then if you want check which labels were no selected, you just do simply loop

```
for (MyJLabel label : rollHumanLabels) {
    if(!label.isSelected()){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to work with the logic that you provided, then the simplest thing to do would be to add JLabel parameter to constructor of MyMouseListener, and compare it this way:

```
public class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

private final JLabel origin;

public MyMouseListener(JLabel origin) {
 this.origin = origin;
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    //compare to origin
  }
}
```